# What should I add in this macro if I want to remove blank cells?

Tags: excel

```
Sub CombineColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim lastCell As Integer

Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1

For iCol = 2 To rng.Columns.Count
   Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol)).Cut
   ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(lastCell, 1)
   lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count
Next iCol
End Sub
```

---

This macro has been helpful for me to combine multiple columns in one cell. They may have been combined, my problem is that there are at least 5 blank rows between each data.

Here is the sample of my old data (uncombined yet)
    A          B      C
1  Single  Married  Married
2          Married  Married
3          Single

Upon using the macro above, here is what happened:
    A          B       C 
1  Single
2
3
4
5
6
7  Married
8  Maried
9  Single
10
11
12
13
14
15 Married
16 Married

The columns in my worksheet: A-SR ,which is a lot. If only I had a few, I can delete the blank rows manually.

How can I remove those blank rows, there must be something I can add in the macro above to combine multiple columns into one column, with data pasted continuously?

Thanks!

Comment: I was going to suggest that "prefer inline functions to macros", then I realized that C is not the only programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing End Sub with:

```vb
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```